# Select all from one table and count from another and include nulls

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get all ids from one table and a count of transactions from another table.  The trick is that an id may not be listed in the transaction table.  In that case, I want the query to return 0 for that id. (I apologize for the bad formatting)

```
ID Table
ID 
1 
2 
3

Trans Table 
ID    Trans 
1     123 
1     234 
3     345 
3     456 
3     567 

Query results 
ID - Trans Count 
1     2 
2     0 
3     3
```

I have this code, but it just isn't working for me and I can't figure out why.

```
  SELECT A.ID, COUNT (B.TRANS) AS CNT
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.DTE BETWEEN '01-Mar-2017' AND '31-Mar-2017' AND
      A.CURRENT_FLAG = 1
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `left join`, conditions on the first table go in the `where` clause.  Conditions on the second table go in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT A.ID, COUNT (B.TRANS) AS CNT
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON A.ID = B.ID AND
        B.DTE BETWEEN '01-Mar-2017' AND '31-Mar-2017' AND
WHERE A.CURRENT_FLAG = 1
GROUP BY A.ID;
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the value is null if then just replace it with a 0

The NVL Function will work perfect for this scenario.

```
SELECT A.ID, COUNT (NVL(B.TRANS,0)) AS CNT
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.DTE BETWEEN '01-Mar-2017' AND '31-Mar-2017' AND A.CURRENT_FLAG = 1
GROUP BY A.ID
```